# BaseURL in HTML is weak for making a module, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, bower

On the server-side, when file `A` imports file `B` as a moudule, `A` uses a relative path of `B` whose baseURL is `A`'s. But for a brower-side module, suppose I write an UI component named `module-A`. Its file structure looks like this:

```
.
|-- main.js
`-- pic
    `-- c.jpg
```

If I create a element with `<img src="./pic/c.jpg">`, it refers to the right picture.

Then I make it into a package, which looks like this if I use Bower to install:

```
.
|-- components
|   `-- module-A
|       |-- main.js
|       `-- pic
|           `-- c.jpg
`-- index.html
```

Or even like this:

```
.
|-- components
|   `-- module-B
|       `-- components
|           `-- module-A
|               |-- main.js
|               `-- pic
|                   `-- c.jpg
`-- index.html
```

But at this time if I create one more menu at `index.html`, and there will be a tag `<img sc="./pic/a.jpg">` create by JS code in `module-A`. This time it's wrong!

If I want it work, I have to use an iframe to wrapper `module A` then things could be fine, maybe.

For a server-side program, everything works OK, because there no things like HTML to make all the code in one page (I mean programs which have no UI.).

How can I fix this?

---

Update:

Yes I use Bower, and a CommonJS loader SeaJS which it more popular in China rather than RequireJS. I think it's a common problem whether we use package manager or manager files by hand.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using RequireJS? Might be good to mention that...

Comment: Or perhaps you're only using Bower...in any case, some clarification would be good.